# Interstitial Yandex advertising does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, interstitial, yandex-api

Changing the advertising platform in the android studio app.
interstitial advertising does not work, where is the bug?
When you click on the button, InterstitialAd should start does not work

AdMob worked without problems.

InterstitialAd Yandex
https://yandex.com/dev/mobile-ads/doc/android/quick-start/interstitial.html

````
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val interstitialAdEventListener = InterstitialAdYandexAdsEventListener()

    lateinit var consentInformation : ConsentInformation
    lateinit var consentForm : ConsentForm

    companion object {
        fun startActivity(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private lateinit var mBannerAdView: BannerAdView
    private var initialLayoutComplete = false

    private val viewModel by viewModel<MainViewModel>() // Lazy inject ViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val minMeetingCodeLength = 10
    private var currentUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private lateinit var createMeetingInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        setProfileIcon()


        val params = ConsentRequestParameters.Builder()
            .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
            .build()


        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this)
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
            this,
            params,
            {
                if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                    loadForm();
                }
            }
        ) {
            // Handle the error.
        }

        val str_text = "<a href=\"https://videotranslation.ru/?utm_source=android&utm_medium=click\">videotranslation.ru</a>"
        val link: TextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.textMeet2) as TextView
        link.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

        fun TextView.htmlText(text: String){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                return setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                return setText(Html.fromHtml(text))
            }
        }

        textMeet2.htmlText(str_text)



        // Load ads based on configuration
        if (Meetly.isAdEnabled) {


            initializeCreateMeetingInterstitialAd()
            loadCreateMeetingInterstitialAd()

        }

        handleDynamicLink()

        onMeetingToggleChange()
        onCreateMeetingCodeChange()
        onCopyMeetingCodeFromClipboardClick()
        onShareMeetingCodeClick()
        onJoinMeetingClick()
        onCreateMeetingClick()
        onMeetingHistoryClick()
        onProfileClick()

        if (Meetly.isAdEnabled) setupBannerAd() else binding.adViewContainer.makeGone()
    }

    private inner class InterstitialAdYandexAdsEventListener : InterstitialAdEventListener {

        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            Logger.debug( "onAdLoaded")

        }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adRequestError: AdRequestError) {
            Logger.error(adRequestError.description)

        }

        override fun onImpression(impressionData: ImpressionData?) {
            Logger.debug("onImpression")
        }

        override fun onAdShown() {
            Logger.debug( "onAdShown")
        }

        override fun onAdDismissed() {
            Logger.debug("onAdDismissed")

        }

        override fun onAdClicked() {
            Logger.debug( "onAdClicked")
        }

        override fun onLeftApplication() {
            Logger.debug("onLeftApplication")

        }

        override fun onReturnedToApplication() {
            Logger.debug("onReturnedToApplication")
        }
    }




    fun loadForm(){
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
            this,
            { consentForm ->
                this@MainActivity.consentForm = consentForm
                if (consentInformation.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                    consentForm.show(
                        this@MainActivity
                    ) { // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                        loadForm()
                    }
                }
            }
        ) {
            /// Handle Error.
        }
    }


    private fun setProfileIcon() {
        currentUser?.let {
            if (it.photoUrl != null) {
                binding.ivProfile.load(currentUser?.photoUrl) {
                    placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initializeCreateMeetingInterstitialAd() {
        createMeetingInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
        createMeetingInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("R-M-DEMO-480x320")
        createMeetingInterstitialAd.setInterstitialAdEventListener(interstitialAdEventListener)

        
    }

    private fun loadCreateMeetingInterstitialAd() {
        createMeetingInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    }


    private fun handleDynamicLink() {
        Firebase.dynamicLinks
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
                // Получить ссылку с результатом (может иметь значение NULL, если не найдено никакой связи)
                val deepLink: Uri?
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                    deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode")?.let { joinMeeting(it) }

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { _ ->
                toast(getString(R.string.main_error_fetch_dynamic_link))
            }
    }



    /**
     * Called when the meeting toggle button check state is changed
     */
    private fun onMeetingToggleChange() {
        binding.tgMeeting.addOnButtonCheckedListener { _, checkedId, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                when (checkedId) {
                    R.id.btnToggleJoinMeeting -> {
                        binding.groupCreateMeeting.makeGone()
                        binding.groupJoinMeeting.makeVisible()
                    }
                    R.id.btnToggleCreateMeeting -> {
                        binding.groupJoinMeeting.makeGone()
                        binding.groupCreateMeeting.makeVisible()
                        val meetingCode = generateMeetingCode()
                        binding.etCodeCreateMeeting.setText(meetingCode)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the meeting code in the EditText of the CREATE MEETING toggle changes
     */
    private fun onCreateMeetingCodeChange() {
        binding.tilCodeCreateMeeting.etCodeCreateMeeting.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
            if (text.toString().trim()
                    .replace(" ", "").length >= minMeetingCodeLength
            ) binding.tilCodeCreateMeeting.error = null
        }
    }

    private fun generateMeetingCode(): String {
        val allowedChars = ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')
        return (1..10)
            .map { allowedChars.random() }
            .joinToString("")
    }

    /**
     * Буфер обмена Called when the clipboard icon is clicked in the EditText of the JOIN MEETING toggle
     */
    private fun onCopyMeetingCodeFromClipboardClick() {
        binding.tilCodeJoinMeeting.setEndIconOnClickListener {
            val clipboardText = getTextFromClipboard()
            if (clipboardText != null) {
                binding.etCodeJoinMeeting.setText(clipboardText)
                toast(getString(R.string.main_meeting_code_copied))
            } else {
                toast(getString(R.string.main_empty_clipboard))
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the share icon is clicked in the EditText of the CREATE MEETING toggle
     */
    private fun onShareMeetingCodeClick() {
        binding.tilCodeCreateMeeting.setEndIconOnClickListener {
            if (isMeetingCodeValid(getCreateMeetingCode())) {
                binding.tilCodeCreateMeeting.error = null
                toast(getString(R.string.main_creating_dynamic_link))

                Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync {
                    link = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_deep_link_url, getCreateMeetingCode()))
                    domainUriPrefix = getString(R.string.app_dynamic_link_url_prefix)
                    androidParameters {}
                    navigationInfoParameters {
                        forcedRedirectEnabled = true // Directly open the link in the app
                    }
                }.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                    val shortDynamicLink = result.shortLink.toString()
                    startShareTextIntent(
                        getString(R.string.main_share_meeting_code_title),
                        getString(R.string.main_share_meeting_code_desc, shortDynamicLink)
                    )
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    toast(getString(R.string.main_error_create_dynamic_link))
                }
            } else {
                binding.tilCodeCreateMeeting.error =
                    getString(R.string.main_error_meeting_code_length, minMeetingCodeLength)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the JOIN button is clicked of the JOIN MEETING toggle
     */
    private fun onJoinMeetingClick() {
        binding.btnJoinMeeting.setOnClickListener {
            if (isMeetingCodeValid(getJoinMeetingCode())) {
                if (Meetly.isAdEnabled) {
                    if (createMeetingInterstitialAd.isLoaded) createMeetingInterstitialAd.show() else joinMeeting(
                        getJoinMeetingCode()
                    )
                } else {
                    joinMeeting(getJoinMeetingCode())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun joinMeeting(meetingCode: String) {
        MeetingUtils.startMeeting(
            this,
            meetingCode,
            R.string.all_joining_meeting
        ) // Start Meeting

        viewModel.addMeetingToDb(
            Meeting(
                meetingCode,
                System.currentTimeMillis()
            )
        ) // Add meeting to db
    }

    /**
     * Returns the meeting code for joining the meeting
     */
    private fun getJoinMeetingCode() =
        binding.etCodeJoinMeeting.text.toString().trim().replace(" ", "")

    /**
     * 
     */
    private fun onCreateMeetingClick() {
        binding.btnCreateMeeting.setOnClickListener {
            if (isMeetingCodeValid(getCreateMeetingCode())) {
                if (Meetly.isAdEnabled) {
                    if (createMeetingInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) createMeetingInterstitialAd.show() else createMeeting(
                        getCreateMeetingCode()
                    )
                } else {
                    createMeeting(getCreateMeetingCode())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createMeeting(meetingCode: String) {
        MeetingUtils.startMeeting(
            this,
            meetingCode,
            R.string.all_creating_meeting
        ) // Start Meeting

        viewModel.addMeetingToDb(
            Meeting(
                meetingCode,
                System.currentTimeMillis()
            )
        ) // Add meeting to db
    }

    private fun getCreateMeetingCode() =
        binding.etCodeCreateMeeting.text.toString().trim().replace(" ", "")

    private fun isMeetingCodeValid(meetingCode: String): Boolean {
        return if (meetingCode.length >= minMeetingCodeLength) {
            true
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(
                binding.constrainLayout,
                getString(R.string.main_error_meeting_code_length, minMeetingCodeLength),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            false
        }
    }

    private fun onMeetingHistoryClick() {
        binding.ivMeetingHistory.setOnClickListener {
            MeetingHistoryActivity.startActivity(this)
        }
    }

    private fun onProfileClick() {
        binding.ivProfile.setOnClickListener {
            val profileDialog = MaterialDialog(this, BottomSheet(LayoutMode.WRAP_CONTENT)).show {
                customView(R.layout.dialog_profile)
            }

            profileDialog.apply {
                if (currentUser != null) {
                    currentUser!!.photoUrl?.let {
                        ivUserProfileDialog.load(it) {
                            placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile)
                        }
                    }
                    tvUserName.text = currentUser!!.displayName
                    tvEmail.text = currentUser!!.email
                    btnUserAuthenticationStatus.text = getString(R.string.all_btn_sign_out)
                } else {
                    tvUserName.makeGone()
                    tvEmail.makeGone()
                    tvUserNotAuthenticated.makeVisible()
                    btnUserAuthenticationStatus.text = getString(R.string.all_btn_sign_in)
                }

                switchDarkMode.isChecked = !AppPref.isLightThemeEnabled

                // UserAuthenticationStatus button onClick
                btnUserAuthenticationStatus.setOnClickListener {
                    dismiss()

                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        // User is currently signed in
                        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this@MainActivity).addOnCompleteListener {
                            AuthenticationActivity.startActivity(this@MainActivity)
                            finish()
                        }
                    } else {
                        // User is not signed in
                        AuthenticationActivity.startActivity(this@MainActivity)
                        finish()
                    }
                }

                // Dark Mode Switch
                switchDarkMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                    dismiss()

                    // Change theme after dismiss to prevent memory leak
                    onDismiss {
                        if (isChecked) setThemeMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) else setThemeMode(
                            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
                        )
                    }
                }

                // Send feedback onClick
                tvSendFeedback.setOnClickListener {
                    startEmailIntent(
                        getString(R.string.app_feedback_contact_email),
                        getString(R.string.profile_feedback_email_subject)
                    )
                }


                // Rate app onClick
                tvRateApp.setOnClickListener {
                    openAppInGooglePlay(applicationContext.packageName, R.color.colorSurface)
                }

                // Share app onClick
                tvShareApp.setOnClickListener {
                    startShareTextIntent(
                        getString(R.string.profile_share_app_title),
                        getString(R.string.profile_share_app_text, applicationContext.packageName)
                    )
                }

                // FAQs onClick
                tvFaqs.setOnClickListener {
                    FaqsActivity.startActivity(this@MainActivity)
                }



                // Privacy Policy onClick
                tvPrivacyPolicy.setOnClickListener {
                    openUrl(getString(R.string.app_privacy_policy_url), R.color.colorSurface)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private fun setThemeMode(themeMode: Int) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(themeMode)
        AppPref.isLightThemeEnabled = themeMode == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
    }


    private fun setupBannerAd() {

        mBannerAdView = BannerAdView(this)
        binding.adViewContainer.addView(mBannerAdView)
        binding.adViewContainer.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            if (!initialLayoutComplete) {
                initialLayoutComplete = true

                mBannerAdView.setAdUnitId("R-M-DEMO-320x50")
                mBannerAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER_320x50)
                mBannerAdView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            }
        }



    }


}```
````